# Как отменить Exeption в equals?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-ee

Как отменить Exeption в equals?

```
 public List<SubTitleModel> vttParsingStart(){

  for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
        textLine = stringList.get(i);
        textLine = textLine.trim();

        if (textLine.substring(13, 16).contains("-->")){
            allTextVtt="";
            readLineBoolean=true;
            subTitleModel=new SubTitleModel();
            subTitleModel.setTimeStart( parseTimeCode(textLine.substring(0, 12)) );
            subTitleModel.setTimeEnd( parseTimeCode(textLine.substring(17)) );
        }

        if (readLineBoolean){
            if (textLine.isEmpty()) {
                readLineBoolean=false;
                subTitleModel.setText( allTextVtt );
                subTitleModelArrayList.add(subTitleModel);
                continue;
            }
            allTextVtt+=textLine;
        }

    }

    return subTitleModelArrayList;
}
```

На этой строчке я испльзовал и constains и eqluals. Все равно выкидывает Exeption `if (textLine.substring(13, 16).contains("-->")){`

Что я хочу сделать? Я хочу чтобы если в строке нет --> то курсор двигался дальше.

Да я соглаасен что можно просто добавить на проверку еще и WebVTT из - за которого и вылетает Exeption. Но все же в данном файле кроме WebVTT много разных динамический символов. И делать для каждого проверку это не вариант.

Как использовать equals или constaint чтобы не выыкидывало Exeption. Типо просто проверил есть совпадение заходишь в if. нет совпадения идешь дальше

Comment: Ошибка-то какая? Наверное выход за длину строки? Если да - то проверяйте длину строки.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; regionStart=13; regionLength=3` Это после того как программа проверяет данный if с текстом `WebVTT`

Comment: Я кажется понял

Comment: Сделал дополнительную проверку если нет --> то пропускаем. спс тема закрыта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас исключение `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, возникающее при попытке порезать строку на части, которые за пределами её длины. Вам надо лишь проверить длину строки перед её резкой. Если она меньше некоторой величины - ничего не делать.